# SQLSTATE[42P01]: Undefined table: 7 ERREUR: la relation n'existe pas

Tags: laravel, migration

This is the migration :

```
class CreateRevdepensesTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('revdepenses', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('libelle');
            $table->string('type');
            $table->decimal('montant', 10, 2);
            $table->string('description')->nullable();
            $table->date('date');
            $table->string('payement');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

In my route i wrote :

```
Route::resource('revenu','RevenusController');
```

In the RevenusController method index:

```
 public function index()
    {
        $rev = RevDep::all();
        return view('revenu', compact('rev'));
    }
```

My modal :

```
class RevDep extends Model
{
    protected $fillable=['id','libelle','type','montant','description','date','payement'];
}
```

And this is my view revenu.blade.php (I'm just tesing with hello)

```
@extends('index')
@section('content')
<h1>hello</h1>
@endsection
```

[I got this error, the table "rev_deps" doesn't exist, in fact i don't have this table because i dropped it and i re-create a migration named "revdepenses"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xNYTp.png)

ps: i try with php artisan migrate:refresh and fresh , and still not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your model class, you will have to mention the name of the table, since your table name does not follow the convention. So

```
class RevDep extends Model
{
    protected $table = "revdepenses";
    protected $fillable=['id','libelle','type','montant','description','date','payement'];
}
```

Comment: @Bharat_Geleda I got another error : View [revenu] not found.

Comment: Where is your view stored?

Comment: in a directory named "Finance"

Comment: If the file is stored at `resources\views\Finance\revenu.blade.php`, in your controller file return it as `return view('Finance.revenu', compact('rev'));`

Comment: Also have a look at https://github.com/alexeymezenin/laravel-best-practices#follow-laravel-naming-conventions which will help you with naming conventions.